# Trouble with MAC address in iOS 7.0.2

Tags: ios, ios7, mac-address

From iOS 7.0.2 the MAC address is: 02:00:00:00:00:00.
How can I read real one in iOS?
Is this unvailable from 7.0.2, or not?
How do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a privacy change, so there's no way to get at the underlying MAC address. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=8222013a

> If your apps use the MAC address to identify an iOS device, the system will return the same static value for all devices running iOS 7. Please update your apps to use the [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) property of UIDevice. If you need an identifier for advertising purposes, use the [advertisingIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ASIdentifierManager/advertisingIdentifier) property of ASIdentifierManager.

Comment: Thx @ceejayoz. It is a very big news for me. Do you know, the solutions in links give a unique values ever or not? (sorry for E)

Comment: May this change in future in a single unique user? After OS update etc. ?

Comment: @skippy Your questions are answered in the linked documentation. Advertising identifier can be reset by the user in the settings (similar to clearing cookies in a web browser) at any time. The vendor identifier can also change, but only if the device is wiped or the user deletes *all* of your apps.