# Manage ifaddrs to return MAC addresses as well in Swift

Tags: swift, ip-address, mac-address

I've got the following code that successfully retrieves all the IPs connected to my router. But I need to a get the MAC Addresses for each IP.

So instead of addresses being returned as an array with `[ips]`, be returned as a dictionary `[ips:0000000, mac: 000000]`

Is it possible to be achieved with changes to the following code (from [How to get Ip address in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift))?

```
func getIFAddresses() -> [String] {


print("GET IF ADDRESSSE")

var addresses = [String]()

// Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs> = nil
if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {

    print("getifaddrs\(getifaddrs)")

    // For each interface ...
    for (var ptr = ifaddr; ptr != nil; ptr = ptr.memory.ifa_next) {
        let flags = Int32(ptr.memory.ifa_flags)
        var addr = ptr.memory.ifa_addr.memory

        print("flags\(flags)")
        print("addr\(addr)")

        // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
        if (flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING) {



            if addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET) || addr.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6) {

                print("addr.sa_family\(addr.sa_family)")

                // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                var hostname = [CChar](count: Int(NI_MAXHOST), repeatedValue: 0)

                print("hostname\(hostname)")

                if (getnameinfo(
                    &addr, socklen_t(addr.sa_len),
                    &hostname,
                    socklen_t(hostname.count),
                    nil,
                    socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {


                        if let address = String.fromCString(hostname) {
                            addresses.append(address)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    print("freeifaddrs\(freeifaddrs)")
}
print("ADDRESSES \(addresses)")
return addresses
```

}

Comment: Have you tried it? Does the code work? If not what is wrong?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu You are correct and am removing the comments. I should have known better than to try and explain why down votes were generally not recommended. And yes, I have had my answer copied and used as an answer on another question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*Remark/clarification:* This is an answer to the question *"Manage ifaddrs to return MAC addresses as well in Swift"* and *"Is it possible to modify the code from [How to get Ip address in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift) to return the MAC addresses as well".*
This is not a solution to *"retrieve all the IPs connected to my router"*
which is also mentioned in the question body.)

Here is an extension of the referenced code which returns
the local (up and running) interfaces as
an array of *(interface name, ip address, MAC address)* tuples.
The MAC address is retrieved from the interfaces of type `AF_LINK`
which are stored as `sockaddr_dl` structure in the interface list.
This is a variable length structure, and Swift's strict type system makes some pointer juggling necessary.

**Important:** This code is meant to run on Mac computers. 
It does not work to get the MAC addresses on iOS devices. 
iOS *intentionally* returns "02:00:00:00:00:00" as hardware address
for all interfaces for privacy reasons, see for example
[Trouble with MAC address in iOS 7.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097888/trouble-with-mac-address-in-ios-7-0-2).)

```
func getInterfaces() -> [(name : String, addr: String, mac : String)] {

    var addresses = [(name : String, addr: String, mac : String)]()
    var nameToMac = [ String : String ]()

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs> = nil
    if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {

        // For each interface ...
        var ptr = ifaddr
        while ptr != nil {
            defer { ptr = ptr.memory.ifa_next }

            let flags = Int32(ptr.memory.ifa_flags)
            let addr = ptr.memory.ifa_addr

            if let name = String.fromCString(ptr.memory.ifa_name)  {

                // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
                if (flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING) {

                    if addr.memory.sa_family == UInt8(AF_LINK) {
                        // Get MAC address from sockaddr_dl structure and store in nameToMac dictionary:
                        let dl = UnsafePointer<sockaddr_dl>(ptr.memory.ifa_addr)
                        let lladdr = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<Int8>(dl) + 8 + Int(dl.memory.sdl_nlen),
                                                         count: Int(dl.memory.sdl_alen))
                        if lladdr.count == 6 {
                            nameToMac[name] = lladdr.map { String(format:"%02hhx", $0)}.joinWithSeparator(":")
                        }
                    }

                    if addr.memory.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET) || addr.memory.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6) {
                        // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                        var hostname = [CChar](count: Int(NI_MAXHOST), repeatedValue: 0)
                        if (getnameinfo(addr, socklen_t(addr.memory.sa_len), &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                            nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {
                            if let address = String.fromCString(hostname) {
                                addresses.append( (name: name, addr: address, mac : "") )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    }

    // Now add the mac address to the tuples:
    for (i, addr) in addresses.enumerate() {
        if let mac = nameToMac[addr.name] {
            addresses[i] = (name: addr.name, addr: addr.addr, mac : mac)
        }
    }

    return addresses
}
```

You have to add

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
```

to the bridging header file to make this compile.

Example usage:

```
for addr in getInterfaces() {
   print(addr)
}
// ("en0", "fe80::1234:7fff:fe2e:8765%en0", "a9:55:6f:2e:57:78")
// ("en0", "192.168.2.108", "a9:55:6f:2e:57:78")
// ...
```

---

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8):**

```
func getInterfaces() -> [(name : String, addr: String, mac : String)] {

    var addresses = [(name : String, addr: String, mac : String)]()
    var nameToMac = [ String: String ]()

    // Get list of all interfaces on the local machine:
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return [] }
    guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return [] }

    // For each interface ...
    for ptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
        let flags = Int32(ptr.pointee.ifa_flags)
        if let addr = ptr.pointee.ifa_addr {
            let name = String(cString: ptr.pointee.ifa_name)

            // Check for running IPv4, IPv6 interfaces. Skip the loopback interface.
            if (flags & (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_LOOPBACK)) == (IFF_UP|IFF_RUNNING) {
                switch Int32(addr.pointee.sa_family) {
                case AF_LINK:
                    // Get MAC address from sockaddr_dl structure and store in nameToMac dictionary:
                    addr.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr_dl.self, capacity: 1) { dl in
                        dl.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: 8 + Int(dl.pointee.sdl_nlen + dl.pointee.sdl_alen)) {
                            let lladdr = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0 + 8 + Int(dl.pointee.sdl_nlen),
                                                             count: Int(dl.pointee.sdl_alen))
                            if lladdr.count == 6 {
                                nameToMac[name] = lladdr.map { String(format:"%02hhx", $0)}.joined(separator: ":")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                case AF_INET, AF_INET6:
                    // Convert interface address to a human readable string:
                    var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))
                    if (getnameinfo(addr, socklen_t(addr.pointee.sa_len),
                                    &hostname, socklen_t(hostname.count),
                                    nil, socklen_t(0), NI_NUMERICHOST) == 0) {
                        let address = String(cString: hostname)
                        addresses.append( (name: name, addr: address, mac : "") )
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)

    // Now add the mac address to the tuples:
    for (i, addr) in addresses.enumerated() {
        if let mac = nameToMac[addr.name] {
            addresses[i] = (name: addr.name, addr: addr.addr, mac : mac)
        }
    }

    return addresses
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spending some time on it. I appreciate. Sorry about not adding your credits to my question when used your code.

Comment: this code intends to get all devices connected in the wifi network or my local machine info only?

Comment: @GuiSoySauce: This is for the interfaces on the local machine (the same is true for the referenced code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626117/how-to-get-ip-address-in-swift and the code http://www.chrisandtennille.com/code/IPAddress.c from your previous question).

Comment: @Martin R how to add if_dl.h inside a modulemap for swift framework am getting this error : " Declaration of 'u_char' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.sys.types' before it is required "

Comment: @SOUAHamza: I haven't worked  with module maps yet, so I cannot answer that question. I might try it later, when I have the time, but I cannot promise anything.

Comment: @Martin R I resolved the problem , it's in this answer link that i added :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036255/declaration-of-u-char-must-be-imported-from-module-darwin-posix-sys-types-be

Comment: @Martin R Is it possible to get network interface status(active/inactive)?

Comment: @CocoaUser: You can check for IFF_RUNNING in the flags.

Comment: @Martin R, let status = (Int32(ptr.pointee.ifa_flags) & IFF_RUNNING). but I get 64 for any NICs.

Comment: @CocoaUser: I am afraid that I cannot help. I can only suggest to check all interface flags (IFF_RUNNING, IFF_UP, ...) if they provide the wanted information.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use this inside a framework, you have to add a .modelmap file with this configuration inside it

```
module ifaddrs [system]  [extern_c] {
    header
    "/Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/ifaddrs.h"
    export *
}

module net [system]  [extern_c] {

     module types {
         header "/usr/include/sys/types.h"
         export *
     }

     module if_dl {

         header
         "/usr/include/net/if_dl.h"
         export *
     }

 }
```

and then in your .swift file

```
import ifaddrs
import net.if_dl
```