# Can not initialize UnsafePointer

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I am trying to initialize an unsafe pointer

```
func f1()
{
    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
    // ....
    // .... collect ifaddr value

    var d1 = UnsafePointer<sockaddr_dl>(ifaddr) 
}
```

and received the below error in the last line of code:

> `init` is unavailable: use `withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)` to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.

the posted answers to a similar problem are unclear to me, can anybody help with fixing this sample code?

Comment: Could you please your use case? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Which "unclear answers to a similar problem" are you talking of? – Does this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34016247/1187415 help?

Comment: See [Swift3 changes](https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html).